# Scala: Matrix construction as Partially applied function

Tags: scala

I am writing a custom generic Matrix class made out of two Vectors.
Currently my constructor just needs an array of arrays of whatever type you want matrix to be.

```
case class Matrix[V: ClassTag](private val arr: Vector[Vector[V]])
```

So the construction of it looks like this:

```
val a = new Matrix(Vector(
    Vector(1,1,1),
    Vector(2,5,2),
    Vector(3,6,3),
  ))
```

I was hoping I can create something like a partially applied function where I could build Matrix such as this:

```
  val a = new Matrix(1,1,1)(1,1,1)(1,1,1)(1,1,1)
```

I tried to achieve this with a mixture of apply functions where you keep putting another row to the Matrix, however the need for the ClassTag causes problems (as its passed implicitly to keep type if I understand correctly).

Is this possible? I had trouble finding answer and the best code I could have produced to get the same effect is only for a specific type, and requires another empty apply to finish, and its a different class than the companion object of Matrix.

```
object MatrixBuilder {

  def apply(elems: Int*): MatrixBuilder =
    new MatrixBuilder(Vector(elems.toVector))
}

class MatrixBuilder(val array: Vector[Vector[Int]]) {

  def apply(elems: Int*): MatrixBuilder =
    new MatrixBuilder(array.appended(elems.toVector))

  def apply(): Option[Matrix[Int]] =
    Matrix(array)
}
```

Which Gives me:

```
val xx = MatrixBuilder(1,1,1)(1,1,1)(1,1,1)(1,1,1)()
```

Comment: Why do you need a `ClassTag`? Also, what about being a little bit more verbose like: `Matrix.empty[Int].addRow(1, 1, 1).addRow(2, 2, 2).addRow(3, 3, 3)` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more why you are looking for the form `new Matrix(1,1,1)(1,1,1)(1,1,1)(1,1,1)`?